# How to draw peanut flavor into rest of dish?

Tags: flavor, curry, peanuts

I've tried on many occasions to cook with peanuts into curries just by roasting them slightly and allowing them to simmer with the rest of the dish, and no matter how long I wait, the peanuts themselves always taste flat and the rest of the flavor just disappears.

Is there a conventional way to pull this off? The peanuts I'm using are stale which is part of it I'm sure, but when I eat them raw they still taste like peanuts.

Comment: What are your expectations? Is there a dish you are trying to re-create?

Comment: For God's sake, first roast them peanuts more, until they smell heavenly!

Comment: I tried roasting them, then someone else said to not do that and only add them at the very end.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the full peanut flavour, use peanut butter; crunchy or smooth.
If you still want the texture effect of whole nuts, add them at the end.

It's a bit like using coconut oil to lift up the taste of coconut that you just can't get in any other way.

Answer (score 2):

First, obviously, don't use stale peanuts. (unless there's a typo in your question)

Second, add the peanuts at the end of the cooking; just before serving your dish.

They will keep their texture and "freshness".